# Can't select edgeloops with shortcut; no emulate 3 selected, keymap settings on, using default cube,

Tags: modeling

My emulate 3 isn't selected, I'm in edit mode selecting edges, my keymaps look normal, other shortcuts work fine to my knowledge...what am I doing wrong? I'm on a mac, I tried restarting blender but that didn't fix it. Is factory reset my only option? I don't want to have to reinstall stuff and redo other settings, but I'm at a loss

Comment: Should just be ALT- click (or the equivalent on a Mac). Can you include an image of the object you're trying to select edge loops on in Edit mode? In Blender, Window > Show Screenshot. Then follow this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: There are no edge loops on default cube...

Answer (score 0):

To select an edge loop you have to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click an edge, to select an edge ring - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+click:

[image]

There is also Multi Select Loops operator that selects multiple loops from all selected edges. You can find it in the Select menu or by searching for it with search menu(<kbd>F3</kbd>).

[image]